# Instagram posting comments with Selenium limit

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I have one problem, Ive searched and I see the limits on instagram and nowdays are:
-Maximun 1440 comments per day
-60 comments max per hour, minimum 1 comment per minute

Ive already done a Script with python and selenium that in one post in its comments, I tag my followers, I put comments with delay 95s-120s and I dont exceed the limit 60 per hour, and when I put 4 o 5 users, depends sometimes each 6, I get this:
`The comment could not be published.'`
I refresh automatically the web each five comments.
What can I do?

[image: The comment could not be published]

Answer (score 0):

Check the console logs.

And Also try to do in the browser yourself.

Also It could be honeypot

Comment: I get noticied that are some accounts that the owner desactivate the comments with its user, but Already I have problems, what do you refer do it in my browser yourself? and honeypot? I run it on my personal pc with my browser

Comment: If the accounts closed comments no one can do the comment. However, Honey pot is security trap that capture the bots by their headers,fingerprints etc. So that, You have to simulate as an human by using headless browsers. I recommend you to try playwright if you want some help let me know. Although, I am not expert as well but moderate enough.

Comment: oooh thank you, I want some help plis, Im starting in this world of programming bots, and I need some guidance on the topic